# Regex to get value between two colon excluding the colons

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
something:POST:/some/path
```

Now I want to take the POST alone from the string. I did this by using this regex

```
:([a-zA-Z]+):
```

But this gives me a value along with colons. ie I get this:

```
:POST:
```

but I need this

```
POST
```

My code to match the same and replace it is as follows:

```
String ss = "something:POST:/some/path/";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":([a-zA-Z]+):");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
    ss = ss.replaceFirst(":([a-zA-Z]+):", "*");
}
System.out.println(ss);
```

**EDIT:**

I've decided to use the lookahead/lookbehind regex since I did not want to use `replace` with colons such as `:*:`. This is my final solution.

```
String s = "something:POST:/some/path/";
String regex = "(?<=:)[a-zA-Z]+(?=:)";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(s);

if (matcher.find()) {
    s = s.replaceFirst(matcher.group(), "*");
    System.out.println("replaced: " + s);
} 
else {
    System.out.println("not replaced: " + s);
}
```

Comment: Grab Group 1 value - `matcher.group(1)`

Comment: This works when I print the matcher. But how can I replace it in the string using the regex ?

Comment: See my answer showing how to do both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches:

- Keep your Java code, and use lookahead/lookbehind `(?<=:)[a-zA-Z]+(?=:)`, or
- Change your Java code to replace the result with `":*:"`

**Note:** You may want to define a `String` constant for your regex, since you use it in different calls.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Since replacing with colons does not look good, I wanted to handle it with a regex.

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE

Looking at your update, you just need `ReplaceFirst` only:

```
String result = s.replaceFirst(":[a-zA-Z]+:", ":*:");
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/KrlBIB)

When you use `(?<=:)[a-zA-Z]+(?=:)`, the regex engine checks *each location inside the string* for a `*` before it, and once found, tries to match 1+ ASCII letters and then assert that there is a `:` after them. With `:[A-Za-z]+:`, the checking only starts after a regex engine found `:` character. Then, after matching `:POST:`, the replacement pattern replaces the whole match. **It is totlally OK to hardcode colons in the replacement pattern since they are hardcoded in the regex pattern**.

## Original answer

You just need to access Group 1:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/O6SCIO)

Your `:([a-zA-Z]+):` regex contains a *capturing group* (see `(....)` subpattern). These groups are numbered automatically: the first one has an index of `1`, the second has the index of `2`, etc.

To replace it, use `Matcher#appendReplacement()`:

```
String s = "something:POST:/some/path/";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(":([a-zA-Z]+):").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result, ":*:");
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/uVsAr4)

Comment: This works for printing. But not for replacing I guess.

Comment: You can assign it to a variable. To replace it, a `Matcher#appendReplacement` should be used.

Comment: Note that you can actually drop the parentheses completely from the pattern since you know a match will start and end with colons, and what is inside will be dropped and replaced with `*`.

Comment: I do not want to use a StringBuffer. Also I do not want to replace my string with colons. So I think the lookahead/behind works for me. Thanks. ^ed

Comment: What do you need to get in the end? Lookarounds are "expensive".

Comment: I see your update. That's what I said. I do not want to use colons in my replace with portion, since if someone else touches the code and misses the colon, it would break the code. So I just want to keep only the word to be replaced.

Comment: also ideone is blocked by my organization , so can't see your demos :( will check them once I am home.

Comment: Just use `import java.util.regex.*;` and use the code snippets above. The first one does not require that.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, the reqex captured group can be used to replace.

The following code did it:

```
  String ss = "something:POST:/some/path/";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":([a-zA-Z]+):");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        ss = ss.replaceFirst(matcher.group(1), "*");
    }
    System.out.println(ss);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution:

regex = `(:)([a-zA-Z]+)(:)`

And code is:

```
String ss = "something:POST:/some/path/";

ss = ss.replaceFirst("(:)([a-zA-Z]+)(:)", "$1*$3");
```

ss now contains:

> something:*:/some/path/

Which I believe is what you are looking for...